# Python: How to get dropdown for options when typing code?

Tags: python, arguments, dropdown

*A very quick beginner question:*

How do you trigger the dropdown for available options for arguments, in a called function/module, when typing code in Python? I'm using the Spider environment.

This is for example regarding the **yfinance** module, where when typing the code, I would like to be able to press "ESC", and then receive the various options that I can choose from, e.g. the different options regarding intervals:

**Example:**
apple = yf.download('AAPL', start=start, end=end, **interval='1wk'**)

The valid intervals for yfinance are:
"1m,2m,5m,15m,30m,60m,90m,1h,1d,5d,1wk,1mo,3mo".

So, I would like to be able to choose from these options from a dropdown when typing that argument.

Is this a certain environment/package I need to install to enable this, or am I actually requesting a functionality that does not exist for all modules?

Best, Nic

Comment: I don't think this functionality exists for any of the IDEs as this is not a language feature.

Answer (score -1):

Use the Tab button on your keyboard and the dropdown will show.